Some users cant upload profile picture Wordpress
I am running a wordpress site with Ultimate Member. Some of my users are not able to upload a profile picture anymore. When trying to upload a profile picture, the user get the "ERROR:" on screen.
When watching the console log in the browser of the affected users, i get this error:

This is what i have tried:

Conflict test: Disabled all plugins
Deactivate Cache plugin

Im not an expert on this. Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Thank you so much

Hi Simen, have you checked the documentation from the plugin provider Ultimate Member? Photo/image uploads not working.  If you have a caching plugin installed, try purging the cache as well.

Hi, and thank you so much for getting back to me. I have tried to change the folder permission, but did removed profile pictures and cover photos for all my users. And affected users still cant upload photos.
When i check the console log in the browser and choose "Response" i can see this message: "Spam detected".
